# Need help understanding this recursive function tutorial

Tags: javascript, recursion

I came across this example of a recursive function in a textbook. I can see there are other threads on this site that ask a question about this very example from Eloquent JavaScript but that user's difficulty in understanding the example was to do with not understanding how functions are invoked in general.

```
function findSolution(target){
  function find(start, history){
    if(start == target)
      return history
    else if(start > target)
      return null
    else 
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)") 
    }
    return find(1, "1");
  }
```

You supply a target number to the findSolution function, and it executes the inner function, find, which calls itself until it finds a way to reach the target number by adding 5 or multiplying by 3. Say I supply the number 13 as a target to reach. The parameters increment as follows.

```
Start = 1 + 5, History = "(1 + 5)"
Start = 6 + 5, History = "(1 + 5) + 5"
Start = 11 + 5, History = "(1 + 5) + 5) + 5"
```

Start becomes 16, and this is higher than 13, so this will return null. So the find function tries to multiply start by 3 instead of adding 5, going back to 11...

```
Start = 11 * 3, History = "(1 + 5) + 5) * 3"
```

This is also too high, and will so return null. Surely the function stops here, right??

When I test it out though, console logging the start values each time find recursively calls itself, it continues to call itself until it reaches number 13. The start values the function cycles through after 33 are:

```
18
3
8
13
```

But how is any of this possible? Shouldn't the function just return false after it reaches 16 and 33?

Comment: The cycle comes from the way you recall your function. You trigger it twice with the logical OR "||" and the Stop condition can stop only one of them. The best solution would be to rewrite your test : if (start + 5 <= target) then ... else if (start * 3 <= target) then ...else Return NULL

Comment: This recursion is nuts. It is a kind of double-recursion, in which the second recursive call depends on a logical disjunction. It is obfuscated and annoying. Let it go.

Comment: @ftor Yeah I'll probably never use this in any of my work ever. But it was just vexing me that I didn't get what was going on. Had a colleague explain it to me and I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Console.log history just before the base case. That will help to understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your (the) example code. It should appear like this:

```
function findSolution(target){
    function find(start, history){
        if(start == target)
            return history
        else if(start > target)
            return null
        else 
            return (find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
                    find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)"))
    }
    return find(1, "1");
  }
```

(Note the structure of the last return in the inner function.)

When running the updated function with an input of 13, I see this in the console:

> (((1 * 3) + 5) + 5)

Comment: Yes but this doesn't answer my question. My confusion was about how the code runs until start is equal to 16. This will cause the find function to return null, and attempt to multiply start by 3, producing the value 33, which again calls find to return false. This means that the two conditions in the third conditional block will each return false. My understanding of how return and how booleans work tell me that the function should stop executing. But as I have shown, and you realize, it continues calling itself until it finds a solution -- But HOW? :s

Comment: It's also worth noting the function works either way, with or without the parentheses you've added.

Comment: I added the parentheses for readability. You asked "Say I supply the number 13 as a target to reach" - the output shows how 13 is reached

Comment: Ok, let me clarify. The function calls itself until the parameter start equals 16. Because this is higher than 13. The second method of multiplying by 3 is applied to the former start value 11. This produces 33. At which point the function - to the best of my understanding - should stop executing. Instead it executes 4 more times. I'm confused as to why this should happen.

Comment: @SerGaweyne at every depth if addition doesn't work it does multiplication so at 33 it returns `null` back to the part that is having `start` = `6` and tries multiply from that. If that doesn work it backtrackes back to `1` and tried multiply with that and from there it does the additions untill it matches. If it wouldn't it would have backtracked again.. If there are no solutions `find` on `1=5` and backtrack to `1*3` will both fail returning `null` since `null || null //==> null`

Comment: I cannot see that your code is significantly different or better than OP. Both lacks semis and you seem to have added redundant parentheses. I cannot see this answers OP "how it is possible".

Comment: I only wanted to change the OPs code as minimally as possible in order for it to work, not refactor it completely, and he **clearly** stated it was example code from a textbook. Yes I hate missing curly braces and semicolons as much as the next man, but the question was not 'How can I make this code more readable'. Plus, it looked like the premise of the question was false, because the OP was asking 'how could this work' when in fact, it **didn't** work.

Comment: ^ You were right that I had an extra return in there in the last conditional block that was stopping what I typed out from working ... buuut this would have been more appropriate as a comment than an answer. Jus sayin' ;)